# positioning diagrams inside tables?

Tags: tables, diagrams, positioning

[image]Could I ask if this is the best way to position diagrams? or should I be using a different method other than in a table?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\newcommand{\AB}{0.75}   % A  and B added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\C}{1.5}    % C added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\AD}{0.75} % D added<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\Asize}{0.25}   % Angle added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\AG}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoints{-\AB/0/A,\AB/0/B,0/\C/C,1/\AD/D}

        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=0.5](B,C)\tkzGetPoint{E}

    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
    %\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,D)

    \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
    \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
    %\tkzLabelPoints[above](D)
  
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,C)
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=||](A,B)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=\Asize](B,A,C)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=\Asize](C,B,A)
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \tkzDefPoints{-\AB/0/A,\AB/0/B,0/\C/C,1/\AD/D}

     \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=0.5](B,C)\tkzGetPoint{E}

    %\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,D)

    \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
    \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
    %\tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](D)
  
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,D)
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,B)
    %\tkzMarkAngle[size=\Asize](B,A,C)
    %\tkzMarkAngle[size=\Asize](C,B,A)
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{-\AB/0/A,\AB/0/B,0/\C/C,1/\AD/D}

        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=0.5](B,C)\tkzGetPoint{E}

    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,D)

    \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
    \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](D)
  
    %\tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,D)
    %\tkzMarkSegment(D,C)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=\Asize](B,A,C)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=\Asize](C,B,A) 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I know people helped me on this to get it this way but I am just trying to improve myself. I am just a little worried all my code seems a bit all over the place, I am just trying to tidy it up a bit. Including all the repeating code for each diagram.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot to your question? What do you like about your current solution, what do you dislike (besides non-refactored Tikz-code) ?

Comment: Why not simply put the 3 codes in sequence?

Comment: I just think all the code looks messy, it might just be me. But I am constantly finding I am doing things the long way round and not the 'proper' way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could I ask if this is the best way to position diagrams?

Since you haven't specified any optimality criteria for positioning diagrams in an appealing manner, it's not possible to judge what may be *best*. Your method certainly works -- which is always a plus.

That said, it doesn't appear to be the case that the `tabular` machinery really adds any extra capabilities that aren't available by simply placing the diagrams next to each other, separated by `\quad`, `\qquad`, or (say) `\hspace{1cm}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}

\newcommand{\AB}{0.75}  % A and B added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\C}{1.5}    % C added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\AD}{0.75}  % D added<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\Asize}{0.25} % Angle added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\AG}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
%%%\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzDefPoints{-\AB/0/A,\AB/0/B,0/\C/C,1/\AD/D}
   \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=0.5](B,C)\tkzGetPoint{E}

    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
    %\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,D)

    \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
    \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
    %\tkzLabelPoints[above](D)
  
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,C)
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=||](A,B)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=\Asize](B,A,C)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=\Asize](C,B,A)
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hspace{1cm} %%% &
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoints{-\AB/0/A,\AB/0/B,0/\C/C,1/\AD/D}
    \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=0.5](B,C)\tkzGetPoint{E}

    %\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,D)

    \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
    \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
    %\tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](D)
  
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,D)
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,B)
    %\tkzMarkAngle[size=\Asize](B,A,C)
    %\tkzMarkAngle[size=\Asize](C,B,A)
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hspace{1cm} %%% &
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoints{-\AB/0/A,\AB/0/B,0/\C/C,1/\AD/D}
    \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=0.5](B,C)\tkzGetPoint{E}

    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,D)

    \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
    \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](D)
  
    %\tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,D)
    %\tkzMarkSegment(D,C)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=\Asize](B,A,C)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=\Asize](C,B,A) 
\end{tikzpicture}
%%%\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

For my taste, we can have the same result, only with the `tikz` package and with this more simpler code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) node[below] (A) {A}--(3,0) node[below] (B) {B}--(1.5,4) node[above] (C) {C}--cycle;
        \draw (.5,0) arc(0:69.44:.5);
        \draw (2.5,0) arc(180:110.56:.5);
        \draw (0,0)--(1.5,4) node[pos=.5,sloped] () {|};
        \draw (0,0)--(3,0) node[pos=.5] () {||}; 
        
        \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
            \draw (0,0) node[below] (A) {A}--(3,0) node[below] (B) {B}--(4.14,1.04) node[above] (D) {D}--cycle;
            \draw (0,0)--(4.14,1.04) node[pos=.5,sloped] () {|};
            \draw (0,0)--(3,0) node[pos=.5] () {||};
        \end{scope}
        
        \begin{scope}[xshift=11cm]
            \draw (0,0) node[below] (A) {A}--(3,0) node[below] (B) {B}--(1.5,4) node[above] (C) {C}--cycle;
            \draw (.5,0) arc(0:69.44:.5);
            \draw (2.5,0) arc(180:110.56:.5);
            \draw (0,0)--(3,0)--(4.14,1.04) node[right] (D) {D}--cycle;
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is this one:

[image]

You can use almost the same code (and coordinates) for each picture.